# Making the as3 dragon breath

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs4

Ok i have a mc called dracoplay and inside is another mc called Drakep and inside that there is another mc called wing and head as you may have guessed they make up a dragon. So dracoplay is the character that gets coded. Drakp is the body and the head and wing have animations. Now my problem is making it breath fire so that it will keep firing until i let go of the left click (I already found a way for it fire when i click but i have to click again for it to stop). I would also like for it to shoot towards the mouse.

Comment: I think i already got this answered but it is pretty much how to shoot with the mouse like a machine gun. But answer it because it would probably help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from what i'm seeing, you should use two eventListeners, a mouseDown and mouseUp-event :) I'll write some basic code that should help you.

```
public function constructor():void
{
     stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, toggleFire);
     stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, toggleFire);
}
```

these two eventListeners should be added in the constructor of your code. Then, the toggleFire-method will look like this:

```
private function toggleFire(e:MouseEvent):void
{
     if(e.type == MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN)
          stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, breatheFire);
     else
          stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, breatheFire);
}
```

the last function you need is the breatheFire-function.

```
private function breatheFire(e:Event):void
{
     //Write your code for the fire breathing here
}
```

and this should do the trick.